# How to save Int to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to save the int named "curmov" to a text file so it can be accessed again at a later date. I keep on getting a TypeError: must be str, not int. I need it to stay an int.any thoughts

```
curmov = 21
def savemov():
    global curmov
    text_file = open("curmov.txt", "w+")
    text_file.write(curmov)
    text_file.close()
```

Comment: Note, in your sample code, `global curmov` is unnecessary.

Comment: Hmm didn't know that I always put it there out of habit. thx mgilson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it to a string

```
text_file.write(str(curmov))
```

You can still use `curmov` as an `int` in your function. This will just make a temporary `string` copy and write it to file. As far as the file cares, it doesn't know if it's an `int` `float` or `duck`, everything is a string!

Comment: Convert strings to ints with the int() function, e.g. int('1234') returns the integer 1234.